# Proper workflow to translate / work on csv files

Tags: csv, localisation, workflow

We are developing our magento store with 3 languages with a bunch of customized modules. And the current translation workflow is slowing our project.

The current workflow is: Open each csv file with PHP's IDE and translate line-by-line. Therefore, things became more difficult while lines don't have the same length and the double-quote `"` is sometime skipped on editing.

We'd like to know the better way to translate magento, or **a software which could help opening csv files in 2 columns and saving as csv format: separated by comma with `"` as text qualifier**.

We tried Microsoft Excel but it messed up the files (it sometime can't specify correct `,` and  `"`). We tried Aegisub but it seems like it's not the good tool for csv files.

Thanks

Comment: LibreOffice Calc works well with CSV, you can specify the delimiters while opening the file and it saves it in the same format.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much @fschmengler. That would be until now the best to work on csv files.